# Why is my downloaded JSON file not JSON any longer?

Tags: json, swift

I am downloading a JSON file, which I have checked to be valid JSON with "https://jsonlint.com" to the document directory. Then I open the file and check it again and it comes out as invalid JSON. How is that possible???? Here is the code:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

        documentsURL.appendPathComponent("analysis."+pathExtension)
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }

Alamofire.download("http://www...../analysis.json", to: destination).response { response in
        if response.destinationURL != nil {
            print(response.destinationURL!)

            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
            let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

            let path = documentsDirectory + "/analysis.json"

            if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(path) {
                 print("Valid Json")
            } else {
            print("InValid Json")     ///// I am getting here "INValid Json" - how is that possible????
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1418461-isvalidjsonobject checks if your object (usually a dictionary or array of dictionaries) can be converted to json data not the opposite

Comment: Because you are trying to check the file long before it is actually downloaded.

Comment: OK, what do you want me to do?

Comment: I moved the code for checking JSON into the Alamofire download function. I guess this would only be executed when the file is downloaded??

Comment: your code makes no sense. Where is  docURL coming from? What type is it? Again this method it is not to check the data returned by your api. It check is your object is valid object that can be encoded. You need to decode your json data.

Comment: sorry, corrected it. replaced docURL with "path". still not working though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `path` is a string indicating the location of a file on your system, something like `file://path/to/analysis.json`. That is obviously not valid JSON.

What you want to check is the *content* of that file being valid JSON. Try this:

```
Alamofire.download("http://www...../analysis.json", to: destination).response { response in
    guard detinationURL = response.destinationURL else { return }
    guard data = Data(contentsOf: destinationURL) else { return }

    do {
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("InValid Json")
    }
}
```

On a side note: why not use `Decodable`?

Comment: above worked with one change: put the guard data statement within the do{} brackets and changed it to let data = try Data(contentsOf: destination1)

Comment: it was still not working, but then I did this:  let data = try Data(contentsOf: destination1)
                let string1 = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Data could not be printed"
                in order to see what I actually downloaded. It was NOT the JSON file because the file on the server was called analysis.JSON and I put analysis.json. I really did not know that this was case sensitive. Finally it is working!!!